# Relations of set operators: closure, interior, complement

Tags: general-topology

For a proof related to one of the versions of Baire's category theorem I needed the following equality:
$$\operatorname{cl} \! \big( \!\operatorname{int} (A^c)\big) = \operatorname{int} \! \big( \! \operatorname{cl} (A)\big)^c \quad \text{ for a set } A.$$ I was a little baffled that the author thought I should just come up with this "out of the blue" as it didn't seem obvious that something like this could be appropriate. I was looking for a comprehensive list of rules (à la De Morgan's), which I could just memorize for the future, but I couldn't really find anything.

What's the philosophy behind being able to apply suchlike transformations when needed? I saw that there are plenty specific equalities proven on here – but I'd like to approach this more generally. Thankful for any pointers at "main rules" to keep in mind or a genereal direction/works/articles where to look for answers.

Comment: A good starting point would be the definitions of closure, interior, and complement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X$ is the space in which you’re working, you always have

$$\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A$$

and

$$\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus A)=X\setminus\operatorname{int}A\;.$$

These complementary relationships between interiors and closures are pretty fundamental and should be part of your basic ‘tool set’, and they’re exactly what’s needed here:

$$\operatorname{cl}\operatorname{int}(X\setminus A)=\operatorname{cl}(X\setminus\operatorname{cl}A)=X\setminus\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}A\;.$$

In fact they’re a bit reminiscent of De Morgan’s laws:

- the closure (interior, resp.) of the complement is the complement of the interior (closure, resp.) *versus*
- the union (intersection, resp.) of the complements is the complement of the intersection (union, resp.).